Unable to upload file in NFT.Storage
Tried to upload image (jpeg,png) to nft storage IPFS, but unable to upload as the code throws the error as:

Error uploading file to IPFS: Error
at pRetry__default.default.retries (C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\EMPVERIFY\node_modules\nft.storage\dist\src\lib.cjs:242:23)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async RetryOperation._fn (C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\EMPVERIFY\node_modules\p-retry\index.js:50:12)


upload.js
const router = express.Router()  
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

const { NFTStorage, File } = require('nft.storage');

const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');

const client =  new NFTStorage({ token: process.env.NFT_STORAGE_API_TOKEN })

router.post('/uploadToIPFS', upload.single('studentDocument'), async (req, res) => {
const { originalname: fileName, path: tempFilePath, mimetype } = req.file;

    try {
        const fileData = await fs.readFile(tempFilePath);
         const metadata = await client.store({
             name: req.body.name || 'File',
             description: req.body.description || 'description',
             image: new File([fileData], fileName, { type: mimetype })
         });
    
         const cid = metadata.ipnft.toString();
        const metadata = await client.storeBlob(blob)
        console.log(metadata)
catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading file to IPFS:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to upload file to IPFS' });
    } finally {
        await fs.unlink(tempFilePath);
    }
})

index.ejs
<html>
<body>
<form id="documentUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="d-flex justify-content-between">
 <input type="file" name="studentDocument" class="form-control w-50 ps-2 " style="height: 35px;">
 <button type="submit" id="docUpload" class="btn btn-lg  fw-bolder form-btn py-1 px-3  float-end">click to Add
</button>
<script>


document.getElementById('docUpload').addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            
            const form = document.getElementById('documentUploadForm');
            const formData = new FormData(form);
            try {
                const response = await fetch('/uploadToIPFS', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData ,
                });
                
                if (response.ok) {
                    const data = await response.json();
                   console.log(data)
}
})

</script>
</body>
</html>

Tried to upload image (jpeg,png) to nft storage IPFS but the above code throws an error as unable to upload file but I followed the docs

Not sure if this is related but NFT.storage is changing how they operate and soon will not allow uploads at all (source). You could check out some other providers and how they do uploads instead,
